# useContext is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I get the following error when using `const [state, setState] = useContext(Context)`:

`useContext is not a function or its return value is not iterable`

Not sure why as I've done this multiple times before. This is my set up:

My `State.jsx` file:

```js
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const Context = createContext()

const initialState = {
    tasks: {}
}

const State = ({children}) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}

export default State;
```

Used as a wrapper in `App.jsx`:

```js
import State from './state'
import TaskList from './components/TaskList'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <State>
      <TaskList />
    </State>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Trying to access the state in `TaskList.jsx`:

```js
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Context } from '../State';

const TaskList = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useContext(Context)
  
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Task list</h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default TaskList
```

Which returns the error specified before, any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Error log]

Comment: Why do you think this would work? Please read about useContext here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: @idmean why you say that? The code looks legit to me. What make you think it wouldn’t work?

Comment: @idmean It's based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnt2y7D3V9o) tutorial, which I've used before. Seems to match the documentation?

Comment: The error message is quite peculiar. Is it a lint error or runtime error? If runtime error can you also post the full error stack?

Comment: @hackape It's a runtime error, added a screenshot with the error.

Comment: Hmm, weird. It’s first time I ever see an error complaining about 2 diff things and couldn’t tell you which precisely… Try this: `const value = useContext(Context)` and maybe console.log the value to see if error message change.

Comment: @hackape Interesting, for some reason `value` returns `undefined`..

Answer (score 4):

When using the `useContext` hook, the returned value is a single object, not an array. Therefore, the correct syntax to destructure the context value would use curly braces instead of square brackets.

In `TaskList.jsx` change the following statement.

```js
const [state, setState] = useStateContext();
```

To

```js
const {state, setState} = useStateContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

`State.jsx`

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

 const Context = createContext();

const initialState = {
  tasks: {}
};

const State = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[state, setState]}>{children}</Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default State;
export const useStateContext = () => useContext(Context);
```

`TaskList.jsx`

```
import { useStateContext } from "./State";

const TaskList = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useStateContext();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Task list</h1>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state)}</pre>
    </>
  );
};

export default TaskList;
```

Wow working fine...

Comment: If it works by exporting `export const useStateContext = () => useContext(Context);`, then it should also work by exporting just `Context` and importing it like `import { Context } from "./State";` before manually calling `const [state, setState] = useContext(Context)` , like I'm doing, right?

Comment: Exactly i have also tried like that and working fine . I have just added some better practices here.

Comment: Above code worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const Context = createContext([initialState, () => {}])
```

Supply a dummy default value to `createContext` should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you, but I found the cause of the issue. Added it to the thread.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in `App.jsx`:

```
import State from './state'
import TaskList from './components/TaskList'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <State>
      <TaskList />
    </State>
  )
}

export default App;
```

My state is called `State.jsx`, but as you can see I'm importing it from `'./state'` without capital `S`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).